# GMock EXPECT_CALL returns FAILED while comparing two char arguments inside the method

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

As the tittle, I'm using gmock to test my feature. But one of the issue occurred that EXPECT_CALL always check address of 2 char array instead of their value.
Below is my code example:

Base.h

```
//Create singleton class
class Base {
 private:
  static Base* _ptrInstance;
 public:
  static Base* getInstance();
  void sendString(const char* text, int value);
};
```

Base.cpp

```
#include "Base.h"
Base* Base::_ptrInstance = NULL;
Base* Base::getInstance(){
   if ( NULL == _ptrInstance ){
      _ptrInstance = new Base();
   }
   return _ptrInstance ;
}
void Base::sendString(const char* text, int value){
 //do something
}
```

Here is the function that need to be tested:
test.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Base.h"
int Test(){
 Base* poBase;
 char text[] = "hello_world";
 poBase->getInstance()->sendString(text, 0);
 return 0;
}
```

my MOCK method:

```
MOCK_METHOD2(sendString, void (const char* text, int value));
```

here is my test case:

```
TEST_F(myTest, sendStringTest){
EXPECT_CALL(*BaseMock, sendString("hello_world", 0));
Test();
}
```

When I execute my test. It always return above test case FAILED:

```
Expected arg #0: is equal to 0x56e88a0d pointing to "hello_world"
           Actual: 0xffcb1601 pointing to "hello_world"
         Expected: to be called once
           Actual: never called - unsatisfied and active
```

With given failure, I though that EXPECT_CALL is comparing argument addresses instead of their value.
(Here, text[] address created in Test.cpp and "hello_world" address inside EXPECT_CALL)

Is anyone know how to overcome this failure?
Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks Jarod42 for the answer, it works now for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
EXPECT_CALL(*BaseMock, sendString("hello_world", 0));
```

You compare pointer.

According to [reference/matchers.md](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/main/docs/reference/matchers.md), You might use `StrEq`

```
EXPECT_CALL(*BaseMock, sendString(StrEq("hello_world"), 0)));
```